# Disable page behind on processing using Javascript in MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dialog

I am using MVC4 in my project. On click of a button on a page, I need to show a dialog and then on confirmation, I need to do an event processing.

```
  $('#btn1).click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var meetingvar = new Array();
            var cells = $(this).closest('td').siblings('td');
            meetingvar = $(cells[2]).text().split(",");
            var params = {};
            params.meetingdate = meetingvar[0];
            params.meetingstate = meetingvar[1];
            params.meetingvenue = meetingvar[2];

            $.ajax(
                            {
                                type: 'GET',
                                url: '/[Controler]/[action1],
                                data: { MeetingDate: params.meetingdate, MeetingState: params.meetingstate, MeetingVenue: params.meetingvenue },
                                beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                                    setLoaderLabel('Please wait...');
                                    showLoader();
                                }
                            }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) //success callback
                            {
                                if ($.trim(data) == 1) {
                                    var dialog = $('<p>Confirmation Required. Do you want to overwite ?</p>').dialog({
                                        buttons: {
                                            "Yes": function () { //alert('you chose yes'); 
                                                window.location.href = '/[Controller]/[Action2]?MeetingDate=' + meetingvar[0] + '&MeetingState=' + meetingvar[1] + '&MeetingVenue=' + meetingvar[2] + '&toGen=1';
                                            },
                                            "No": function () { //alert('you chose no'); 
                                                window.location.href = '/[controller]/[action2]?MeetingDate=' + meetingvar[0] + '&MeetingState=' + meetingvar[1] + '&MeetingVenue=' + meetingvar[2] + '&toGen=0';
                                            },
                                            "Cancel": function () {
                                                dialog.dialog('close');
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                if ($.trim(data) == 0) {
                                    showLoader();
                                    window.location.href = '/[controller]/[action1]?MeetingDate=' + meetingvar[0] + '&MeetingState=' + meetingvar[1] + '&MeetingVenue=' + meetingvar[2] + '&toGen=1';
                                }
                                if ($.trim(data) == 2) {
                                    ShowErrorMessage('<p>NOT DEFINED</p>');
                                }
                            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) //error callback
                            {
                                var errorMsg = GetAjaxResponseTitle(jqXHR.responseText);
                                ShowErrorMessage('<p>' + errorThrown + '</p>' + errorMsg);
                                hideLoader();
                            }).always(function () //complete callback
                            {
                                hideLoader();
                            });


        });
```

Here , on success, from first action1 is it going to success, with the Loader(basically disabling the main page). But I need the same Loader functionality on Click of Yes or No, because, before redirecting  there is an event which takes some time. At this stage, shouldn't allow user to click on any other button on the base page. Don't know how to achieve this. Please appreciate any help.

Thanks In advance

Comment: where is that time taking event in your code ?

Comment: window.location.href = '/[Controller]/[Action2]?MeetingDate=' + meetingvar[0] + '&MeetingState=' + meetingvar[1] + '&MeetingVenue=' + meetingvar[2] + '&toGen=1'; This is an action taking place here which Is executing a stored procedure with lots of calculation. Hence redirecting to next page takes time. In the meantime, I need to blovk the base page or give a processing image so that any click on the base page is restricted

Comment: Are you sute it is  a time taking process ? If yes, why not call the showLoader method just before that line ?

Comment: It is consuming time for the calculation, I tried to give the showloader there, but its not working. Now, when I click on the button, it triggers action, it is processing which I can identify from the explorer bar.(which is processing) but  the page is open for clicking on any other button.This is to be restricted by disabling the page. Need help for that. Thanks

Comment: What calculation are you talking about ? Since you are not hiding the loader in your success, you will still have the loader shown until the redirect

Comment: Hi... Actually in [Controller]/[Action2] I have a stored procedure which is picking up data from database and loading on to next view using windo.location.href. I am referring to that time. Now, during this time, the first page from where the button is clicked, is totally enabled and anyone can click on any other button while the other action is taking place., The showLoader() is not working there. Basically I need to disable the first page after the button is clicked before redirecting to next view.